# With sys_language_mode = strict, how to access relations in main language

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

For an extbase extension in a 3 language site, records are only created in Language 0.

To access these records with `sys_language_mode = strict`, each repository has an extended `findAll()` method:

class ApprenticeshipTimeframeRepository extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Repository {

```
/**
 * @return array An array of objects, empty if no objects found
 * @api
 */

public function findAll() {

    $query = $this->createQuery();

    $query->getQuerySettings()->setRespectSysLanguage(FALSE);
    $query->getQuerySettings()->setSysLanguageUid(0);

    $result = $query->execute();
    return $result;
}
```

}

This works - but not for ObjectStorage (?) Properties

From the model:

```
/**
 * Initializes all ObjectStorage properties
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function initStorageObjects() {
    $this->apprenticeshipFree = new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage();
    $this->apprenticeshipOccupied = new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage();
    $this->apprenticeshipUnavailable = new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage();
    $this->internshipFree = new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage();
    $this->internshipOccupied = new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage();
    $this->internshipUnavailable = new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage();
    $this->contactPerson = new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage();
}
```

All of these are not output in translated versions of the page.
How can I force these to access L=0?

PS: maybe related with https://forge.typo3.org/issues/47192?

Comment: If you want them to be available for all languages, why don't you set the language to -1 (all)?

Comment: Lorenz, I didn't even know that possibility existed! But how do I set that as a default for the sysfolder the records are in? I can't expect the editor to choose the "right" language each time s/he creates a record.

Comment: Use `TCAdefaults.tx_yourext_domain_model_foo.sys_language_uid = -1` in Page TSconfig. You need to add this config for every table so that also child records have this language uid. TBH I'm not sure if it works well with IRRE, but please test and give feedback.

Comment: I can't test yet, as we have switched the config to `content_fallback`, where the issue doesn't appear. I'll do it after the go-live next week with the remaining dev version

Comment: Yes, `TCAdefaults.tx_yourext_domain_model_foo.sys_language_uid = -1` works!

Comment: also with IRRE records